# Sequelize group by with association includes id

Tags: group-by, sequelize.js

So when requesting a group by from sequelize as follows:

```
return models.WorkingCalendar
            .findAll({
                attributes: [
                    'WorkingCalendar.PeriodId',
                    'WorkingCalendar.date',
                    'Period.name'
                ],
                include: [
                    {
                        model: models.Period,
                        attributes: []
                    }
                ],
                where: {
                    GetSudoId: currentGetsudo.id,
                    UnitPlantId: unitPlantId
                },
                group: ['WorkingCalendar.PeriodId',
                    'WorkingCalendar.date',
                    'Period.name'],
            });
```

Sequelize will run this query:

```
SELECT 
[WorkingCalendar].[id],
[WorkingCalendar].[PeriodId], 
[WorkingCalendar].[date], 
[Period].[name] 
FROM [WorkingCalendars] AS [WorkingCalendar] 
LEFT OUTER JOIN [Periods] AS [Period] ON [WorkingCalendar].[PeriodId] = [Period].[id] 
WHERE [WorkingCalendar].[GetSudoId] = 1 AND [WorkingCalendar].[UnitPlantId] = N'1' 
GROUP BY [WorkingCalendar].[PeriodId], [WorkingCalendar].[date], [Period].[name];
```

Yet I never asked for the `WorkingCalender.id` and I cannot seem to get rid of that.
How do I make sure sequelize is not getting me this `id` from the `workingCalendar`?

I've already found that for associations the attributes should be an empty array and that works but not for the main object since I need only 3 columns.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So this is not possible. The ORM needs a relation towards the database and this is done through the id; making it impossible to get this without the id.

What you can do, however, is do a raw query with sequelize.

i.e.

```
return models.sequelize.query(
    `SELECT 
    [WorkingCalendar].[id],
    [WorkingCalendar].[PeriodId], 
    [WorkingCalendar].[date], 
    [Period].[name] 
    FROM [WorkingCalendars] AS [WorkingCalendar] 
    LEFT OUTER JOIN [Periods] AS [Period] ON [WorkingCalendar].[PeriodId] = [Period].[id] 
    WHERE [WorkingCalendar].[GetSudoId] = :getsudoId AND [WorkingCalendar].[UnitPlantId] = N'1' 
    GROUP BY [WorkingCalendar].[PeriodId], [WorkingCalendar].[date], [Period].[name]`,
    {
        replacements: { getsudoId: getsudoId },
        type: models.Sequelize.QueryTypes.SELECT
    }
)
```

Hope this helps anyone struggling too.

Answer (score 1):

Just pass `raw` flag to sequelize and it stops adding id field to attributes at least with sequelize 6:

```
const groups = ['WorkingCalendar.PeriodId', 'WorkingCalendar.date', 'Period.name']

return models.WorkingCalendar.findAll({
  attributes: groups,
  where: { GetSudoId: currentGetsudo.id, UnitPlantId: unitPlantId },
  include: [{ model: models.Period, attributes: [] }],
  group,
  raw: true,
})
```